# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

My debug statement is displaying the database correctly, by after something is going wrong and in getting the error:
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'.
I am getting null data when I'm trying to display is in my application, this is because the list i am using to store the values has length 0.

This is my class:

```
class Values {
  num humidity;
  num temperature;
  num moisture;
  bool led;

  Values({this.humidity,this.temperature,this.moisture,this.led});

}

class RealtimeDB extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RealtimeDBState createState() => _RealtimeDBState();
}

class _RealtimeDBState extends State<RealtimeDB> {

  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Values");
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  List<Values> list = new List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      print("Data: ${snap.value}");  //Debug statement
      var data=snap.value;
      list.clear();
      data.forEach((key,value){
        Values val=new Values(
          humidity: value["Humidity"],
          moisture: value["Moisture"],
          temperature: value["Temperature"],
          led: value["MotorControl"],
        );
        list.add(val);
      });
      setState((){});
    });
  }
```

This is my listview builder:

```
      body: new Container(
        child: list.length==0?Text("Data is null"): new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
            itemBuilder: (_,index){
            return UI(list[index].humidity, list[index].temperature, list[index].moisture, list[index].led);
            }
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This is my simple database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NNEg.png)

This is the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zOor.png)

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add Value model also.. And specify the line where you are getting the error in above code?
+ Just suggestion, you can call UI(list[index]) instead of passing all the arguments

Comment: What is your Motor Control type? Because in screenshot its seems it's holding a single quote

Comment: Motor control type is boolean @dinkar_kumar

Comment: @Pushpendra I just added the value model above, and thankyou for the suggestion!

Comment: @Pushpendra I think I am getting the error after my debug statement.

Comment: what does `print("Data: ${snap.value}");` print?

Comment: @njzk2 It prints `Data: {Temperature: 15, Moisture: 14, Humidity: 12, MotorControl:   }`

Comment: @advikManiar if it's a single set of values, why do you use `data.forEach`?

Comment: @njzk2 Could you please show me what else I could use? I'm kinda a beginner I'm making the app for my college project. Please could you show me the code

Comment: You can just write 

```
Values val=new Values(
          humidity: data["Humidity"],
          moisture: data["Moisture"],
          temperature: data["Temperature"],
          led: data["MotorControl"],
        );
```

Comment: @Pushpendra I did that, now i am getting an error: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num'

Comment: It is because it expects `num`.. you can write - 
int.parse(value["WHATEVER"]) to the value which you expect as an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are getting error while trying to fetch the values

```
  humidity: value["Humidity"],
```

It is because snaps.value is a Json or rather Map Object you can just create a Utility fromMap  and add it to your Values class and also since its a Map you dont need to loop throught it.

```
Values.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map):
    humidity: int.parse(value["Humidity"].toString()),
    moisture: int.parse(value["Moisture"].toString()),
    temperature: int.parse(value["Temperature"].toString()),
    led: value["MotorControl"],
```

and then you could use it like this

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      print("Data: ${snap.value}");  //Debug statement
      Map data=snap.value;
      final value = Value.fromMap(data);
        list.add(value);
      setState((){});
  }
}
```

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'   Now i got this error after i followed your steps, please help! @Mahesh Jamdade

Comment: replace ```Map data=snap.value;``` with  ```Map<String,dynamic> data= snap.value;```
Let me know if this solves I will update the answer

Comment: Still the same error is popping up @Mahesh Jamdade

Comment: replace ```Values.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)``` with ```Values.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map)```
basically you need to make sure the types are same in both places

Comment: Now it says: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num' @Mahesh Jamdade

Comment: you have to parse the values in fromMap check I have updated the answer also I would suggest using int/double instead of num

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!!!!! I owe u my life!!!!!!! @Mahesh Jamdade

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks like this -

```
{Temperature: 15, Moisture: 14, Humidity: 12, MotorControl: false }
```

`data.forEach((key, value) => WHATEVER)`, here your value will be:

15, 14, 12, false..

These are not list and you are accessing them as `value["WHATEVER"]`. That's why. you are getting. "Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'"

What you can do -

```
list.add(
Values(
    humidity: int.parse(value["Humidity"]),
    moisture: int.parse(value["Moisture"]),
    temperature: int.parse(value["Temperature"]),
    led: value["MotorControl"],
),
);
```